# Missing artifact com.android.support:appcompat-v7:jar:23.0.1 in Eclipse with a Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

For some reason I keep getting three dependency errors while trying to build my project in maven, they are:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project tolmarInventory: Could not resolve dependencies for project tolmar.inventory.app:tolmarInventory:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.android.support:support-annotations:jar:23.1.0, android.support:compatibility-v7:apklib:23.0.1, com.android.support:appcompat-v7:jar:23.0.1: Failure to find com.android.support:support-annotations:jar:23.1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

File locations:
C:\Users\John.m2\repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\23.1.0

and

C:\Users\John.m2\repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1

I look in the m2 repository and it says the version I have is v7 23.0.1 and 23.1.0. I am not sure why I need these android dependencies for a JavaFX project that is not going to be run on the phone. Everything I find online refers to the Android SDK, which I am not using for this project, so I am pretty confused. Perhaps the names of the files are incorrect? I have no idea what to do, I have watched a ton of tutorials on maven and have read many issues that people have had, I just can't figure out what to do here. Are these dependencies normal for Java projects? Thanks!

the POM info is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>tolmar.inventory.app</groupId>
<artifactId>tolmarinventoryapplication</artifactId>
<name>tolmarinventoryapplication</name>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<organization>
    <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
    <name>Kirch Industries</name>
</organization>

<properties>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>


<build>

    <finalName>tolmarinventoryapplication</finalName>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.5</version>
            <configuration>

                <mainClass>tolmar.inventory.app.tolmarinventoryapplication.MainApp</mainClass>

                <!-- only required if signing the jar file -->
                <keyStoreAlias>example-user</keyStoreAlias>
                <keyStorePassword>example-password</keyStorePassword>
                <allPermissions>true</allPermissions>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lucee</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pushtorefresh.storio</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>sdklib</artifactId>
        <version>25.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- MigLayout -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
        <artifactId>miglayout-javafx</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging  -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.4.0</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is the first program I am trying to package and it is tough, thanks for the help! I can not figure out how to get this dependency added to the local maven repository, I have taken those jar files that I have and added them manually to the repository, but am not sure if it is right.

Comment: Can you post your pom file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If they aren't required for your project, you can look at your `pom.xml` file and delete `<dependency>` tags that declare those jars and remove those dependencies.

Comment: it says it is required, my app has email capability and utilizes the email api for gmail, that is the only thing I can think of. If you know of any good resources on using maven with a imported project written in JavaFX, that would be good too, I am not 100% sure where the fxml files go, thanks in advance.

Comment: I ended up doing an exclude and that seemed to work ok, I am on to another problem now with getting the sqlite server to communicate properly, thank you for your help.